# Is OracleCoherence the only product that supports complex (non only key-based) queries?

Tags: nosql, oracle-coherence

As you may know Coherence provides "filtering" api against its cache-cluster, like this:

```
// assuming cache cluster is full of ProductEntity objects
NamedCache c = CacheFactory.getCache("products");

Filter vipFilter = new EqualsFilter("productCode", 1);
Filter dateFilter = new GreaterFilter("createDate", new Date() - 48hrs);

List l = c.query(new AndFilter(vipFilter, dateFilter));

...
```

My question - do we have an alternative to Coherence in terms of an ability to
build complex distributed queries againts the key/value store.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GigaSpaces XAP supports this as well, through the use of a *series* of query APIs - query by example, a map interface (the key/value store) that can be used directly as a map as well as through a memcached api. XAP also supports JPA, JDBC, JMS, a SQLQuery capability, and map/reduce.

There's a screencast available that shows a lot of these in operation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jC57mId3SMg

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) supports this via its fairly rich [query language](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying).

Answer (score 0):

You may also look at Cacheonix. It allows you to create your own search mechanisms by traversing all cache nodes in a distributed fashion.

Full disclosure: I am Cacheonix developer.